# ¿Alguien me puede ayudar a entender este código?

Tags: bash, bucle-for, shell, shell-script

Tengo un ejercicio que me dice que explique qué hace este código:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `sort $1`
do
     if grep $2 $i > /dev/null
     then
          echo A
          cp $i /tmp
          exit
     fi
done

echo B
```

Llevo varias horas dándole vueltas y no logro entenderlo bien, lo he ejecutado y a veces imprime "A" por lo que a veces entra en el `if` pero se me escapa.

Lo que más o menos entiendo es que le pasas 2 parámetros, y se hace un `for` que en `i` guarda cada iteración del primer parámetro, por lo que supongo que el primer parámetro sería un archivo y que en `i` se guarda cada línea del mismo.

Después, mediante `grep` se busca el segundo parámetro en el archivo y la salida se redirige a `/dev/null` si la búsqueda existe entra en el `if`, imprime A y copia esa línea en el `dir /tmp` y al final imprime "B"

Lo que no entiendo es por qué entonces si le paso un archivo que contiene las palabras "hola" y "adios" y de segundo parámetro le paso hola no funciona, me dice: "grep: hola: No existe el archivo o el directorio"

En un intento conseguí entrar al `if` poniendo como primer parámetro hola y como segundo parámetro también hola, pero no se ha vuelto a repetir.

Comment: Seguro que esta bien el código?, a mi me parece que ese `grep $2 $i` debería ser `grep $i $1` porque el comando es `grep busqueda archivo`

Comment: Bueno, el ejercicio me venia ya así, con el código ya codificado, pero ahora que lo dices si es es verdad que tal y como viene es como estar buscando una palabra en una palabra

Comment: Aparte de ese error al ejecutar el script tendrías que poner la extensión del archivo `script file.txt hola`, pero tal como lo veo ese `grep` esta mal puesto y no debería funcionar.

Comment: Hola, he probado y ahora al ejecutar me imprime A pero me dice el siguiente mensaje
cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'hola': No existe el archivo o el directorio
(El primer parametro es archivo1.txt y el segundo hola)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que el script haga algo útil, el fichero que le pasas como primer parámetro en `$1` debe contener una lista de nombres de otros ficheros.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos un fichero llamado `ficheros.txt` que contiene:

```
uno.txt
dos.txt
tres.txt
```

Entonces también tendrás que tener estos tres ficheros en la misma carpeta.

Con esa preparación, la forma de invocar tu script sería por ejemplo esta:

```
./script ficheros.txt hola
```

Y entonces lo que haría sería buscar la palabra "hola" en cada uno de los ficheros especificados en `ficheros.txt` y copiar a `/tmp` el primero (por orden alfabético) en que aparezca esa palabra.

### Explicación

```
for i in `sort $1`
```

Un comando encerrado entre *backtiks* (como `` `sort $1` ``) es ejecutado por el shell y todo lo que ese comando volcaría en su salida estándar, es usado como si hubiera sido escrito formando parte de esa línea del script.

En nuestro caso `sort` leería el contenido de `ficheros.txt`, lo ordenaría alfabéticamente y lo mostraría en su salida estándar, por lo que esta línea del script se convertiría en:

```
for i in dos.txt tres.txt uno.txt
```

La variable `$i` irá tomando valores de esa secuencia. Con cada valor hará:

```
if grep $2 $i > /dev/null
```

En nuestro ejemplo `$2` vale `hola` por lo que hará `grep hola $i`. Es decir, en cada iteración buscará `hola` en un fichero de la lista.

Cuando `grep` retorna éxito (no necesitamos conocer su salida y por eso se redirige a `/dev/null`, basta con conocer su *exit code* que es lo que chequea `if`), entonces se ejecuta:

```
      echo A
      cp $i /tmp
      exit
```

Es decir, se emite una "A", se copia el fichero en cuestión a la carpeta `/tmp` y se da por finalizado el script.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, he probado y funciona, solo tengo una duda, lo que he hecho ha sido, como bien has explicado es crear un archivo y dentro he añadido archivo1.txt y archivo2.txt cada uno de estos archivos a su vez contienen la palabra hola pero al ejecutar el script con hola como segundo parametro solo me ha copiado archivo2.txt ¿no deberia copiar tanto archivo1 como archivo2?

Comment: El exit hace que se detenga en cuanto ha encontrado uno. El orden en que los recorre no es el que aparecen dentro del fichero, sino en orden alfabético por el sort. Debería haber copiado archivo1.txt que alfabéticamente va antes que archivo2.txt ¿seguro que esos eran los nombres de los archivos y que ambos contenían "hola"?